# Django: csrf_exempt doesn't work when other server send request?

Tags: django, csrf, django-csrf

**views.py**

```
class OrderPayCheckView(View):

    @method_decorator(csrf_exempt)
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(OrderPayCheckView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return redirect(reverse("home"))
```

I used 3rd-party service (I'm client) and it sends sort of `Notification request(POST)` to `OrderPayCheckView`.

Since this `POST request` is not from my application, I thought that this view should be decorated with `csrf_exempt` so that it doesn't require `csrf token` anymore.

When I tested with `POSTMAN` it works very well: it shows redirected template page as a response body.

However, when this 3rd-party service(server) tried sending `POST` request to this view, it shows an csrf-token authentication errors like this:

(Since errors are in Korean, I translate it)

```
 REQUEST HTTP BODY : imp_uid=imp_1234567890&merchant_uid=merchant_1234567890&status=ready
 REQUEST HTTP STATUS : 403
 REQUEST HTTP BODY : 
 <!DOCTYPE html> 
    <html lang="en"> 
    <head> 
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> 
        <meta name="robots" content="NONE,NOARCHIVE"> 
        <title>403 Forbidden</title> 
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <div id="summary"> 
            <h1>Forbidden <span>(403)</span></h1> 
            <p> CSRF authentication failed. </p>
            <p> The reason this message shown up is that this https site require "reference header" from your browser, but didn't receive anything abuout it. This header is required for security.</p>
        </div>
    </body> 
</html>
```

What's wrong with it? Do sender have to add specific `reference header` to its request?

Answer (score -1):

**Edit:** This is not the right answer and is not necessary

You didn't decorate the `post` method

```
@method_decorator(csrf_exempt)
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return super(OrderPayCheckView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

@method_decorator(csrf_exempt)
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return redirect(reverse("home"))
```

Comment: This service must be hitting more than one endpoint. Check your web server logs.

Comment: What do you mean by "hitting more than one endpoint"?  I use `gunicorn` but nothings come up in a log

Comment: Do you proxy gunicorn behind nginx or some other webserver? Check the access log to verify the endpoints that the apparent IP address is accessing on your django app.

Comment: I think the problem may be that the redirect to `"home"` is a POST and is including the POST data. This would mean that Django is using HTTP 307 (not sure if it does). If so, you would need to put `csrf_exempt` on your `"home"` view, which is not ideal. Maybe you can perform the operations that you need to in the handler then redirect with a GET. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Comment: But when I test via `POSTMAN`, it works.... If what you're saying is right, does it have to occur same problem when it tested with `POSTMAN`?